# How do you pin elements to the bottom of a container in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple portfolio website and I want two  tags at the bottom of the screen whenever I navigate down or up the page. So for example, if I am at the top of the page it says my name with three links, "About Me", "My Work", and "Contact". If I click on "About Me" it will navigate me down the page to where I have that section. Then this is where I need help, I want "My Work" and "Contact" at the bottom for easy navigation. I have been trying to figure this out for hours now which is why I am now asking a question on here. I am new to web programming so excuse me. Here is some of my code that is relevant.

```css
#container {
  padding-top: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

#container div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Styling for each indivual link (About Me, My Work, Contact) */
#container div#AboutMe {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 21px;
}

#AboutMe p { 
 padding-right: 60%;
 padding-left: 10%;
 padding-top: 5%;
}

.animatedButtonBody span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.animatedButtonBody span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.animatedButtonBody:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.animatedButtonBody:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="AboutMe">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>
     This is where some text will go.
    </p>
    <a href="#MyWork" class="animatedButtonBody"><span>My Work</span></a>
    <a href="#Contact" class="animatedButtonBody"><span>Contact</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you clarify what you mean by "at the bottom"?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915550/fix-footer-to-bottom-of-page or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788357/css-for-fixed-footer

Comment: So if I click on the "About Me" hyperlink it will navigate me to the section where the "About Me" information is. Then I want two hyperlinks at the bottom of that section that say "My Work" and "Contact". So at the bottom of that specific section.

Comment: Advice for the future - please edit your code and include the minimum required to reproduce the problem. You don't really need anything like `cursor:pointer` in this question. It makes it easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try position:fixed. Also you should tidy up your html elements (wrap things in div, etc.)

Example:

```css
.nav {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content{
  height: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
} 

.footer{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "nav">
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
  </div>
  <div class = "footer"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Also you could replace divs for better html tags (semantically) like <nav>, <footer>. Check them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to my problem. Here is what I added to my  tags.

```css
#pinButton1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform:translateX(-100%)
}
#pinButton2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform:translateX(0%)
}
```

```html
<a href="#AboutMe" class="animatedButtonBody" id="pinButton1"><span>About Me</span></a>
   <a href="#Contact" class="animatedButtonBody" id="pinButton2"><span>Contact</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you can try it. You need an element with "position:fixed", this way it stays on the screen when scrolling.

```
 <style>
        .float-container {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        .about-me {
            position:fixed;
        }
    </style>    
    <div class="float-container>
        <div class="about-me">
            <p>Some Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't want it to stay on the screen when scrolling. I have three different sections on my one page, "About Me", "Contact", and "My Work". At the bottom of the "About Me" section there will be two hyperlinks for contact and my work. Then at the bottom of the "Contact" section there will be two hyperlinks for about me and my work and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `position:fixed` and `position:absolute`.

Link to W3Schools: [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

You didn't clarify what does "at the bottom" mean, therefore I give 2 examples. This is how I understood your question.

If you need buttons to be always in viewport at the bottom of the screen use this example with custom values. Here you have an example how to center an item at the bottom center of the viewport.

```css
#example{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)
}
```

If you need an item to be at the bottom of the page use

```css
#example{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)
}
```

Comment: I used position:absolute but it makes my two <a> tags overlap for some reason. Do you have any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: You should wrap it in a div tags and use position absolute on div tag. It will solve the problem.

Comment: I tried doing that but when I added the div tags it put the two hyperlinks back in the middle of the screen